# SwiftUI Observable Object inside Environment Object does not update view

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I recently came across an issue where I didn't find a way to work around it.
If I place an observable object inside an environment object, my views don't update when a variable is changing.
This is my setup:

inside SceneDelegate I decalre the parent view with environmentObject:

```
 let parent = ParentView().environmentObject(Data())
```

This is the environment Object:

```
class Data: ObservableObject {
    enum Page {
        case pageOne
    }
    var page: Page = .pageOne
    var person = Person()
}
```

now all my views are linked to the parent view:

```
struct ParentView: View {

     @EnvironmentObject var data: Data

     var body: some View {
         VStack {
            if self.data.page == .pageOne {
                PageOne()
            } else {
                Text("No pages")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have a class (I called it "Person"):

```
 import Foundation
 import SwiftUI
 import Combine

 class Person: ObservableObject {

     let objectWillChange = PassthroughSubject<Person,Never>()

     @Published var age = 30 { didSet { objectWillChange.send(self)} }

     func birthday() {
         self.age += 1
         print(age)
     }

 }
```

**And this is where my problem occurs:**

```
 struct PageOne: View {

     @EnvironmentObject var data: Data

     var body: some View {
         Text("\(data.person.age)").onTapGesture {
             self.data.person.birthday()
         }
     }
 }
```

When I tap the text, the age of the person is increasing but the view does not update.
I think I don't even understand why this is happening.
I thought I knew how it works but apparently I don't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like in your case `Person` doesn't have to be a *class*.

You can try this instead:

```
class Data: ObservableObject {
    enum Page {
        case pageOne
    }

    var page: Page = .pageOne

    @Published var person = Person() {
        didSet {
            objectWillChange.send()
        }
    }
}
```

```
struct Person {
    var age = 30

    mutating func birthday() {
        self.age += 1
        print(age)
    }
}
```

---

If you need `Person` to remain a class you can make it `@Published`:

```
class Data: ObservableObject {
    enum Page {
        case pageOne
    }

    var page: Page = .pageOne
    @Published var person = Person() // <- add `@Published`
}
```

and remove unnecessary `objectWillChange` code from `Person`:

```
class Person: ObservableObject {
    @Published var age = 30

    func birthday() {
        self.age += 1
        print(age)
    }
}
```

Then use `Person` as an `@ObservedObject` in the `PageOne` view:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var data: Data

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if self.data.page == .pageOne {
                PageOne(person: data.person) // pass `person` object
            } else {
                Text("No pages")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct PageOne: View {
    @ObservedObject var person: Person // observe `person` directly

    var body: some View {
        Text("\(person.age)").onTapGesture {
            self.person.birthday()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is only a sample code of a big project so I need to use a class

Comment: @Kevin I updated my answer with a solution for a *class*.

Comment: @Ahmadreza What do you mean? I don't see any *count* function.

Comment: @pawello2222, Sorry I meant birthday function. & I fixed it but creating a custom initializer function for updating the value.

Comment: @Ahmadreza You can do `self.person.age = 35`. But I suggest you create a new question - I'll try to help you there.